# hide link in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I need to hide some of the links on my table depending on the value of another column.

```
<tbody>
                    @foreach (var group in Model) {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.Raw(group.Id)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.Raw(group.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.Raw(group.Description)
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>

var InitiatizeGroup = function () {
return {
    init: function () {
        var oTable = $('#groups').dataTable({
            "dom": "flt<'row DTTTFooter'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']],
            "language": {
                "search": "",
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "Prev",
                    "sNext": "Next"
                }
            },
            "aoColumns": [
              {
                  "bVisible": false,
                  "bSearchable": false,
                  "bSortable": false,
              },
              null,
              null,
              {
                  mData: 0,
                  "bSearchable": false,
                  "bSortable": false,
                  sClass: "alignCenter",
                  "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                      return "<a href='/Groups/Details/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Details'><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href='/Groups/Edit/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Edit'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href='/Groups/Delete/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Delete'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a>";
                  }
              }
            ]
        });
    }
  }
}();
```

If the value of the second column is "Users" I want to hide the edit and Delete links.

I was thinking of adding the hide logic to mRender, but I can't figure out how to get the second value since I'm already passing the value of the first column.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third parameter in `mRender` would be an array containing data for all columns. To access value of the second column, use `full[1]`.

Example:

```
              "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                  if(full[1] === "Users"){   
                     data = "<a href='/Groups/Details/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Details'><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href='/Groups/Edit/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Edit'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i></a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href='/Groups/Delete/" + data + "' class='btn icon-only shiny btn-palegreen btn-xs' title='Delete'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a>";
                  } else {
                     data = "";
                  }

                  return data;
              }
```